# How to authorize to Highrise using api_key using C#?

Tags: c#

Hi i want to connect with Highrise from my website using api_key. 
I had developed my website in C#.Net 2.0. I need to fetch contact details from my Highrise account. I had searched Highrise API, stackoverflow and some other blogs also but i did't get any useful information. Please provide me any sample C# code to connect with Highrise using api_Key or Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lookink for a good .NET SDK for Highrise, you should try
http://sdk.welovehighrise.com/